# How can I determine the source (computer) of an event in DropBox?

Tags: dropbox

I have the DropBox windows app installed on multiple computers.  Each of them link to the same account.

Somehow, my account was disassociated with a shared folder.  I see it in the event log as

> You left the shared folder *Folder Name*.

Is there any way to determine which computer the event was triggered from?

Comment: No way that I've been able to find.

Comment: Could the disassociation coincide with the authentication issues at Dropbox on June 19? http://blog.dropbox.com/?p=821

Comment: The 'left folder' event occurred at 12:44 on 6/20.  Looks like that's outside the window of authentication issues.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not through the web interface or any other DropBox application.**

However, I submitted a ticket to DropBox support and they were able to tell me the source of the event.  Then the following exchange occurred.

> Me: Is there any way I could have figured
>   this out on my own or is this info
>   available only from the back-end?
>
> DB Support:  It's only available to us here in tech
>   support.

Comment: Good on you for finding that, but that sucks. That could be a really useful tool for maintaining account security.